# conda install packagename gives deprecation warning

Tags: anaconda

When trying to run `conda install pyproj` (but this happens for any package name), I get this error:

`WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.`

What does that mean? I'm not sure what the conda.compat module is or why it's relevant to installing a package. I'm still able to install packages right now, but should I be worried?

I'm running on windows, and my anaconda version is 4.6.11

Answer (score 28):

**Update:** [conda 4.6.12](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.6.12) has been released, which removes the warning.

This is a bug in conda 4.6.11 as of April, 2019. It should be fixed in an upcoming version of conda. Quoting [msarahan](https://github.com/msarahan) from the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8512):

> Yep, it's a bug. We'll have a fix out early this week. Please ignore
>   it for now. Fix is in [#8507](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/8507) if you'd like to hack it in to your
>   installation yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing to worry about. It's just saying that the compat module will be removed in future since it is not relevant anymore.

Comment: Yes, it can/should be ignored. However, IMO, the warning message is egregious.  It gives no advice as to what the user did incorrectly, or needs to adjust, in order to avoid the warning.  This is not a problem for just the "new players" but for long-standing conda users like myself since the warning message fouls up scripts I have as wrappers around conda that are impacted due to this warning being emitted to stderr.  Thus, I've file an issue to get the maintainers to see what can be done, if anything: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8512

Comment: And I'm also getting some errors trying to specify the "conda environment" to use in my R codes, through "reticulate" functions. I am getting this error since yesterday:      Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       WARNING: The conda.compat modul
                     (right here) ------^